# Laravel: Cache Store [predis] is not defined in Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel v5.7, whenever I am trying to post to login page using axios I am getting an 500 internal server error I somehow and in network tab in the console that specific file returns this:

```
{
    message: "Cache store [predis] is not defined.", exception: "InvalidArgumentException",…}
    exception: "InvalidArgumentException"
    file: "...\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager.php"
    line: 96
    message: "Cache store [predis] is not defined."
}
```

Comment: please do not use images for 'text' content ... "text is text"

Comment: @lagbox Can you answer the question?

Comment: Did you define a `predis` entry in the `stores` array of `config/cache.php`?

Comment: `
'redis' => [
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'connection' => 'default',
],

`
This is defined, followed the steps in the Laravel Docs

Comment: **`redis`** is not the same as **`predis`**; do you have a typo there???

Comment: predis is the php client for laravel right? What do I need to add for predis configuration

Comment: I have no idea; but to solve your error message, you need to add a `predis` entry.

Comment: How do I add a 'predis' entry?

Comment: what is the 'default' cache store set as in your config and env? from the config file: `Supported: "apc", "array", "database", "file", "memcached", "redis"` ... none of those are `predis`

Comment: My default cache store is set as redis, for which we need to install the predis/predis package from composer according to [Laravel's Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redis)

Comment: what is the result of `config('cache.default')`?

Answer (score 2):

In my cache, no matter which cache store I set in my environment, this would ail, including when set to the default 'file'.

Double check that you have not change the name of your stores attribute in your config/Cache.php file.

I found I had change it unintentionally from stores to store.

If you're not using vcs in some fashion, Id recommend starting. I was able quickly find my issue with fresh eyes and a quick trip to my latest commits after find my local was broken, as well as, my new production.

[Bad Commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvG4I.png)

Comment: Same; unintentionally updated `CACHE_DRIVER=cookie`
instead of `SESSION_DRIVER=cookie`

Answer (score 0):

> Before using Redis with Laravel, you will need to install the
>   predis/predis package via Composer:

[more detail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redis#introduction)

```
  composer require predis/predis
```

Comment: I did install the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issue with following error :

```
message: "Cache store [Database] is not defined.", exception: "InvalidArgumentException",…}
```

to fix the error i did below

opened cache.php inside config and replaced

```
 'database' => [
       'driver' => 'database',
       'table' => 'cache',
       'connection' => null,
     ],
```

with

```
 'Database' => [
           'driver' => 'Database',
           'table' => 'cache',
           'connection' => null,
         ],
```

that solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Had an issue with this using php 8.2.8 and laravel 10.10.1 after a major upgrade.

To resolve this, in `config/cache.php` I changed:

```
'stores' => [

 ...

 'redis' =>[
        'client' => 'redis',
    ],

 ...

]
```

to

```
'stores' => [

 ...

 'predis' =>[
        'client' => 'predis',
    ],

 ...

]
```

Which seemed to work.